# How do i get selected value from html.radiobuttonfor in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 radio buttons in MVC bound to a model as shown below. How do i get the selected radio button value in jquery?

```
<label>Yes</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedPerson.is_selected, true, new { @onchange = "ToggleInfo();" })
<label>No</label>
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedPerson.is_selected, false, new {  @onchange = "ToggleInfo();" })
```

The javascript funtion being called is:

```
function ToggleInfo() {
    //Get the selected value here to tell if Yes/True or No/False is selected       
};
```

Comment: USe `$('[name="SelectedPerson"]:checked').val();`

Comment: @Tushar that isn't correct, you forgot the is_selected property.

Comment: Ben did you check my answer ? accept it if works. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two ways, the first is

```
function ToggleInfo() {
    var result = $('[name="SelectedPerson.is_selected"]:checked').val();
};
```

The second is

```
<label>Yes</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedPerson.is_selected, true, new { @onchange = "ToggleInfo(this);" })
<label>No</label>
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedPerson.is_selected, false, new {  @onchange = "ToggleInfo(this);" })

function ToggleInfo(el) {
     var result = el.value;   
 }
```

Here a fiddle for you to check it https://dotnetfiddle.net/FcVRHA

Comment: The first option you gave me worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `onchange` event in both radios, you can simply use `this.value`:

```
function ToggleInfo() {
  console.log(this.value);   
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this works. You have to do something like @onchange = "ToggleInfo(this); to make it works, and change the js function to get the parameter